¿Cómo solucionar ImportError de '_app_ctx_stack' en app de flask?
PS C:\Users\KLIMER\Desktop\crud> & C:/Users/KLIMER/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe c:/Users/KLIMER/Desktop/crud/app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KLIMER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flaskext\mysql.py", line 5, in <module>
    from flask import _app_ctx_stack as _ctx_stack
ImportError: cannot import name '_app_ctx_stack' from 'flask' (C:\Users\KLIMER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\KLIMER\Desktop\crud\app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
  File "C:\Users\KLIMER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flaskext\mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
    from flask import _request_ctx_stack as _ctx_stack
ImportError: cannot import name '_request_ctx_stack' from 'flask' (C:\Users\KLIMER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py)
PS C:\Users\KLIMER\Desktop\crud>



Probé instalando la libreria de pymsql, pensando que eso faltaba y no funcionó.
Luego vi que podria ser que flask y flask-sql estuvieran en diferentes versiones y las actualize a la más reciente e igual no funcionó, estoy haciendo un proyecto de CRUD

GRACIIIIAAAAS MUCHAS GRACIAS

@FJSevilla esa debiera ser una respuesta, no un comentario.

@jachguate, hecho! Lo cierto es que no tenía mucho tiempo para crear una respuesta medianamente decente, aparte de que no estoy muy al día con flask, por eso lo puse como comentario, de paso, a ver si alguien más al día que yo respondia...

Gracias FJ! +1!

Es, como intuías, un problema de incompatibilidad de versiones entre flask (actualizado, a día de hoy, 3.0.3) y flask-mysql (1.5.2).
El tema está en que _request_ctx_stack está marcado como obsoleto desde flask 2.3) y su import generaba ya un warning. En flask 3.x se ha eliminado completamente.
Por su parte, flask-mysql está bastante desactualizado y aparentemente con un mantenimiento deficiente. Dado este desface, dicha extensión intenta importar _request_ctx_stack que ya no existe y de ahí el error. flask-mysql directamente no funciona con flask >= 3.x a día de hoy, de hecho, esta es una de las causas y hay una issue al respecto en su repositorio desde hace meses.
Tienes básicamente tres opciones a día de hoy:

Intentar actualizar el código de flask-mysql para que funcione con flask 3, descartando el uso de _request_ctx_stack en favor de g. Desconozco si este es el único problema.

Bajar la versión de flask a 2.x, debería funcionar sin problemas, aunque tendrás los susodichos warnings si la versión es superior a 2.3.

Dejar de usar la extensión flask-mysql y de ser necesario usar otro módulo para manejar la conexión con MySql. Hace tiempo que no he usado flask y no estoy al día de las opciones. Yo solía usar SQLAlchemy vía flask-sqlalchemy, puedes también mirarte flask-mysqldb que sí parece estar al día con las versiones recientes de Flask-MySQLdb.


La tercera opción sería la más recomendable, segura y menos dolorosa...
